# Is this a ground cover plant?

Tags: identification

What plant is this? It looks [eerily similar to a ground cover plant that has purple flowers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinca_minor).

[image]

Comment: I cannot see the flowers precisely. It seems some sort of Stellaria or Cerastium. I do not consider them as weed, because they have shallow roots, easy to remove and they do not likes summer/sun (and usually they are good winter cover)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi: I was referring to Vinca Minor ground cover plant. The plant in question seem to have a similar leaf shape like that of Vinca Minor and how it spreads out.

Comment: That looks like it'll cover ground all right.